# Starting a Sound at a specified position with CocosDenshion?

Tags: iphone, audio, cocos2d-iphone

It's possible to do stuff like:

1. Reproduce a sound at a specified starting position
2. Reproduce a sound for a certain ammount of time

Using CocosDenshion ?

If so, how ?.

If not...i have any alternatives, like a different sound engine or a certain class in the SDK that would allow me to do both things ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play positional audio with CocosDenshion. See [this tutorial](http://www.crocodella.com.br/2011/05/positional-audio-with-cocos2d-and-cocosdenshion/) for example.

Of course you can also loop sounds, if that's what you meant by question #2. You can always schedule a timer and stop or (better) fade out the sound after a specified amount of time. Programming the timer is of course up to you.

As for an alternative I can highly recommend [ObjectAL](http://kstenerud.github.com/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/). It does everything CocosDenshion does and a few things more, plus its well documented and comes with an excellent demo app with examples for playing positional audio, looping sounds, using stereo channels with panning and fading sounds.

If you don't want to fumble with including a static library in your project have a look at [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com), it comes with ObjectAL (and Cocos2D) already setup and ready to use.

Comment: Thanks, althoug i wasn't refering to positional audio in my first quesion (sorry for not explaining myself better, maybe it was a bad idea to use the term position ), what i want is to reproduce a sound, not always from beggining, for example reproduce the sound at an starting point 0.4 secons after the sound beggining point...do i explain myself ?. Thanks !

Comment: You can do that with ALSource from ObjectAL, for example set the offsetInSeconds property to 0.4f to play the buffered sound from that position.